# How to work with UTF-8 encoded files in a WLATIN1 encoded SAS session?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, sas

Currently, we are using `WLATIN1 (Windows 1252) encoding` on our SAS session server (and there seems to be no upcoming shift to `UTF-8`).

I have an EXCEL file (which is an export from an internet database) which is encoded in `UTF-8` and contains one special character `≥` which is not supported [Wiki refernce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)) in `WLATIN1 encoding`. I know I can read in the EXCEL data using a different encoding like `UTF-8`but still the `ODS` will print `=` instead of `≥`.

I would like to match some strings containing this special character but SAS of course doesn't let me use this character natively. Is there any way to circumvent this?

MWE: Let's assume the EXCEL file contains one variable `a` and one observation `a = 'this is a test ≥'`:

```
data encoding;
set excel;

if a ='this is a test ≥' then
put 'it works';
else 
put 'it does not work';

run;
```

Can this be fixed in any way? I tried `'(*ESC*){unicode "2265"x}'` instead of `≥` but couldn't get it to work. As always, any help/idea is very much appreciated!

EDIT:
We are running `SAS Release 9.4  TS1M5`.
Currently, the read-in of the EXCEL file is done by using `PROC IMPORT`:

```
filename temp "*.xlsx" encoding="utf-8";

proc import datafile=temp out=quality dbms=excel replace;
run;
```

Comment: You need to explain how you are getting the Excel file into your SAS session.  Most likely that step is either failing completely or it might be converting the string.  If it did not fail then display the value of your variable `a` using the `$hex.` format to see what it actually contains.

Comment: What version & level of SAS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in SAS Server environment you will need to setup a server with Unicode support startup settings.

In desktop environment a session can be started with Unicode support from Icon deep in SAS start menu.  The command line is:

```
"C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" 
           -CONFIG "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\u8\sasv9.cfg"
```

The `nls\u8\` config file will have some lines with encoding settings that can only be applied at the startup of the session, as well as pathing to the SAS dlls supporting a utf8 session.

```
…
-SET SASCFG "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\u8"
-DBCS 
-LOCALE en_US
-ENCODING UTF-8
…
```

In a Unicode session the log, of the sample code below, will show a discrimination between ≥ and =, and ODS will output ≥.  The same code in a default SBCS session the ≥ is mapped to = even when the code editor show ≥.

The font of the LOG window should be set to `Consolas` or other UTF-8 aware font.

```
data have;
input; a = _infile_; datalines;
this is a test ≥
run;

data want;
  set have;

  c1 = '≥';
  c2 = '=';
  put "NOTE: " (c:) (=);

  r1 = rank(c1);
  r2 = rank(c2);

  put "NOTE: " (r:) (=);

  if a = 'this is a test ≥' 
    then put "NOTE: " a 'it works';
    else put "NOTE: " a 'it does not work';
run;
proc print data=want;
run;
--------------------
NOTE: c1== c2==
NOTE: r1=226 r2=61
NOTE: this is a test = it works
```

The same code in a default (SBCS) session shows ≥ will have been transcoded to =

```
NOTE: c1== c2==
NOTE: r1=61 r2=61
NOTE: this is a test = it works
```

The Enhanced Editor might be UTF-8 aware in all cases, but (I speculate) when run the submittal is transcoded to the session encoding.

Comment: You are right, the editor itself is `UTF-8` aware even in a `WLATIN1` session. The problem is, that I am not the only one working on this (which is also part of a bigger project) so changing my local session to `UTF-8` is not really an option (though it works, thanks!). Anyway, we decided to drop the special characters in the export (and switched to `windows 1252` encoding for the export) - not ideal but ok for now.